# page navigation with data in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am working on a app where I have a table with about 30 different products. When user selects a product I want to fetch its detail from sqlite database and display it on the next screen. I am planning to display the details in a div with following code:

```
<li><a href="#two" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse"> <img src="Exercises/abs-exercises-air-bike-1.jpg" width="80px" height="80px" /> <h3> Abs</h3><span class="ui-li-count">116</span></a></li>
```

I am able to display the second div with name two but I am not sure how do I identify which link was selected. I need to fetch its details from sqlite database. Can someone please guide me?

Comment: You can use the local storage available in HTML5 for keeping a track of it or else you will be required to use the History to check which was the last one tapped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the product id in a **[data attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)** on the listitem or the anchor:

```
<li><a href="#two" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse" data-prodid="theid"> <img src="Exercises/abs-exercises-air-bike-1.jpg" width="80px" height="80px" /> <h3> Abs</h3><span class="ui-li-count">116</span></a></li>
```

Then handle the click or tap or vclick event on the anchor:

```
$("ul").on("vclick", "a", function(){
    var prodid = $(this).data("prodid");
    //use id to make query and fill in details on page 2
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply it worked great, can you please also tell me how will I get content of h3 tag from the above line.

Comment: $(this).find("h3").html();

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this calls for #HashTag:

```
var theProduct = window.location.hash.slice(1);
```